# jQuery & confirm dialog events not fired

Tags: jquery, events, confirm

Here is the normal events order when I focus out a textbox by clicking on a button:

1. button mouse down
2. textbox focus out
3. button mouse up
4. button click

Now, let's say I add a confirm('some questions bla bla bla'); in the focus out event, here is how events are done:

1. button mouse down
2. textbox focus out

The button mouse up and the button click events are somehow not fired....

I tried to use a custom jQuery dialog and the last two events are still not fired..
Here's a link to the custom confirm Dialog that I used: http://tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/

I would like to understand how I could have the confirm dialog to show modal and then have the last two events fired.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Show the `confirm` in the button click handler, not the mouse down handler. Modal dialogs suspend execution of JS and event handlers are triggered asynchronously, so the last two get skipped.

Comment: I do not show the confirm in the mouse down handler, it is in the focus out handler. I understand they get skipped but how can I have a custom confirm modal dialog have the events triggered after the user has closed the dialog?